# How to make a Cell in Excel Reference itself

Tags: excel

I have a table that contains a column that has a risk score. I want to write a formula to examine each cell and determine if the cell is blank, then make the cell value 100, else leave the cells current value. The code I'm trying to use( For cell D2) is as follows:

=IF(ISBLANK(D2),100,D2)

I'm having trouble doing this due to a cell's inability to reference itself easily and I believe inserting this formula into the cell simply overwrites the cells current value, any thoughts?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with a worksheet formula, you may need to look at a VBA solution.

Comment: If you would like a VBA solution I can provide one of those, however you could copy the column, paste it elsewhere, and then reference that cell in your formula. Though that would not be dynamic and it would be more efficient to use a find and replace. Comment or edit to let me know if you want the VBA solution.

Answer (score 0):

Say the values you want to process are from **D2** through **D100**.  Try this small macro:

```
Sub OneHundred()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("D2:D100").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r.Value = 100
End Sub
```

Adjust the range to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done because I have a spreadsheet that allows this to happen. Part of my formula in cell T3 is as follows: IF(B3="","",IF(B3="Ready","",IF(T3="",TODAY(),T3))) First it checks some other things but at the end it checks itself to see if it is blank. If it is, it writes todays date. Otherwise it just writes itself.

I remember I had to change something in the settings to allow this to happen but I can't find it now.